# GUI Design: Hide/Show controls at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

what is the best idea/technique to do this and I prefer not to create all these at run time and not using the Tabs control:

let's say we have three radio buttons on the form and based on the user selection we want to show him different GUI stuff ( checkbox, listbox, etc ... ) on the same form.

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the controls' [`Visible` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) to `false`.

This will be easiest to do if you put the controls on different panels and show / hide the panels instead of hiding each control separately.

Comment: yes, but I am thinking about the design time that I am actually designing these separate panels and controls inside each of them... so I will drop all these three panel on each other and say panel2.visible = true? ...

Comment: Yes. Make sure that the panels aren't inside of eachother, though.

Comment: @BDotA: Some container controls have automatic layout features, like the FlowLayout panel. You could put all three in, and then only turn one at a time and alignment within the container should always be OK.

Comment: @ FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : nice, actually I was looking for some new technique like this, just using panels is Ok but VB 6.0 could do that too. So I will combine your technique with SLaks technique. thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Controls have a [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property, that makes the control disappear when it is set to False. When a button is clicked, you could write some code that sets certain controls to be invisible.

Comment: Nitpick: The `Visible` property is defined by the `Control` class itself.  _Every_ control has it.